# how to avoid this map's nested loop with lambdas and streams

Tags: java, loops, foreach, hashmap, java-stream

I would like to improve this algorithm avoiding to generate a nested loop, perhaps exploiting stream and java 8 functions.
For each keys i want to create an object (TreeView, an JavaFx's object) and foreach value related at the key create a new "son" for the Tree Object.

```
Map<MyEnum, List<myObject>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
List<TreeItem<String>> product = new ArrayList<>();
myMap.forEach((k,v) -> {  
            TreeItem<String> fatherItem = new TreeItem<String> (k.getName());
            myMap.get(k).forEach(e -> {
                    fatherItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String> (e.getName());
            });
      product.add(fatherItem);
});
```

I'm really curious about how it can be improved. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: The code you have posted isn't legal Java. For example, map should be `Map` and `Map.forEach` takes a `BiConsumer` rather than a `Consumer`. Can you correct the syntax errors in the question?

Comment: Done, sorry, I wrote it late at night.

Comment: You can replace `myMap.get(k)` inside you lambda with `v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make a new method to covert a key and list into a tree item - that will make you code clearer than having in a lambda block:

```
private TreeItem<String> makeTree(MyEnum root, List<MyClass> items) {
    TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<>(root.getName());
    items.stream().map(MyClass::getName).map(TreeItem::new).forEach(tree::add);
    return tree;
}
```

This could be done in a single collector but, really, I don't think it'd make your code any clearer.

Then converting your map to a list of trees becomes:

```
List<TreeMap<String>> trees = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> makeTree(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your map is structured and the output you want to achieve, it is better to use nested loops for better performance. However usage of forEach is discouraged, use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) this way:

```
List<TreeItem<String>> product =
    map.entrySet().stream().map(
    t -> {
          TreeItem<String>father = new TreeItem<>(t.getKey().getName());
          List<TreeItem<String>> children = t.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(u -> u.getName())
                .map(TreeItem::new)
                .collect (Collectors.toList());
         father.getChildren().addAll(children);
         return father;
     }
    ).collect (Collectors.toList());
```